# Glob not getting files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I am trying to use Glob to get files in a directory. I am learning how to use it through [this](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-list-files-in-a-directory-in-python). My code should (so far) be able to print out all of the files in the `files` directory. But instead it is just printing out `['files']`.

My code is at [@EvokerKing/JSON on repl.it](https://repl.it/@EvokerKing/JSON#main.py).

Comment: Please include a [mre] directly in the question.

Comment: I thought a repl.it link was a reproducible example?

Comment: It can be a bonus, but the code must be included directly in the question, as explained in the reference I've linked.

Comment: Also, the repl.it link doesn't even demonstrate the behaviour you claim to see. When I run it, I get `['files/basic.json']` as output, not `['files']`.

Comment: Yeah, that's because I edited it to fit the answer marked below.

Comment: That's the reason why the (original) code should be included in the question, so that the question can be useful for others that have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do this

```
import json
import glob

fileList = glob.glob("files/*")
print(fileList)
```

for finding the files under `files` folder you need to use `files/*`